# showing different design layouts for inner pages in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

How do i show different design layouts for different inner pages in drupal?
also how do i show the outputs from my modules only in specific pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick answer use page templates for different pages .

Please read the following for how to use templates.

http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6

http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/tips-n-tricks/drupal-6-different-page-templates-for-different-content-types/

http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-make-a-drupal-theme

Comment: You should really include the information here, within your answer, rather than link to external pages